# How to call controller internally which is receiving Custom Form Request validation parameter

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm calling controller method `store` from two places. In the first place directly from the form submission, mean once I submit the from `store` method is called.

The second is way is to call `store` method from other method of laravel. Here is the `store` method code.

```
public function store(MedicalAidRequest $request)
{
    //
    if(Auth::check()){
        $medicalAidRequest = session('medical_aid_request', $request->all());
        $medicalAidRequest['user_id'] = Auth::id();
        return $this->aidRepository->add($medicalAidRequest);
    }else{
        session(['medical_aid_request' => $request->all()]);
        return redirect('login')->with('from', 'aid_request');
    }
}
```

I'm using this code because I want to achieve the following requirements.

- Submit the medical aid if the user is logged in.
- if user is not logged in then store the request data in the session and ask for logging, and once the user is logged in then call the `store` method again to retrieve the form data from the session and save to database.

But when I call `store` method internally after logging, validation getting failed due to `MedicalAidRequest` in the `store` parameter which is validating data from the form request before calling the `store` method. So how I can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly:**

Internally you can create a request with valid data and then pass to the `store` method while calling.

You can create request as below:

`$request = new  <Namespace>\MedicalAidRequest();`

Then you can use the replace method to add inputs manually as bellow:

```
$request->replace(['key' => 'value']);
$controller = new YourController();
$controller->store($request);
```

**Secondly**

You can validate the request inside the controller instead of in form request. If you do so, you can pass a flag in the store method for example `$isInternal` if is internal is `true` then don't run the validation. Here is how:

```
public function store($isInternal = false)
{
  if(!$isInternal){
    $this->validate(request(), $this->rules());
  }
  //Rest of the code remain same
}

private function rules():array
{
  //return your rules array here as in the MedicalAidRequest
}
```

Comment: How can call the request? as you added in the first technique.

Comment: $this->store($request); I'm not calling store method from the same controller. I'm calling `store` method from the outside of the controller.

Comment: Then you can just create an instance of that controller. like: `$controller = new YourController();`
`$controller->store($request);`.  Answer updated.

Comment: Do you really think it is authenticated way? creating the instance of controller looking awkward.

Comment: That's a very good question. This is just a solution of the thing you want to achieve. Ideally a method of one controller should not be called from another controller. It's not about authentication(I mean authentic way) it's about code design. You can place your common code in a repository or service. Then call it from controller. This is just a solution of what you told you want to do. How will you call a method of controller form another controller without creating it's instance?

Comment: I have already created the repository `return $this->aidRepository->add($medicalAidRequest);` but I'm facing the problem to handle the form submission for logged out users. I want allow them to fill the form and ask for login.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to forward an *internal call* to *another controller*.

To solve this you have to create a new **request object** with all the needed parameters then let the **app kernel** handle it.
In this way, Laravel would handle the crafted request as if you were doing it in browser.

To do as stated above, create the *request* and call the `handle` method on the app instance:

```php
$request = Request::create($url, $action, $params, $cookies, $files, $headers);

$response = app()->handle($request);

// If needed you can use the response of the internal call
// if ($response->getStatusCode() == 404) {
//     abort(404);
// }
```

If you need that functionality in multiple places, you can decide to *extract* it to its own **trait** (quickest way); or move the logic into its own **class** that you would **bind** in the app container.

The latter way allows to **resolve** the dependency only when it's needed through Laravel's **typehinting injection** from method's signature, or by hand through `app()` instance.

If you would need further explaination about the class extraction/binding, let me know and I will elaborate my answer.